# Combining "if-let" with "OR" so functions may be executed several times on one value

Tags: if-statement, clojure, let

What I am trying to achieve is to execute functions on a value several times when several conditions are met. In particular say we have two variables a and b.

When a is true the value is transformed by the function associated to a, then
when b is true the new value is transformed by the function associated to b.

So when the initial value is 0 and the functions are `inc` and `#(+ 5 %)` we can get 0, 1, 5 or 6.

My approach was as following but not succeed

```
user> (def initial-number 0)
user> (if-let [a true b true] (cond-> initial-number a inc b (#(+ 5 %))))
IllegalArgumentException clojure.core/if-let requires exactly 2 forms in binding vector in user:  clojure.core/if-let (core.clj:1758)
user>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have will work as described if you substitute `if-let` for `let`. All of your conditional logic exists within the `cond->`.

```
(def initial-number 0)

(let [a true  b true]  (cond-> initial-number a inc b (#(+ 5 %)))) => 6
(let [a false b true]  (cond-> initial-number a inc b (#(+ 5 %)))) => 5
(let [a true  b false] (cond-> initial-number a inc b (#(+ 5 %)))) => 1
(let [a false b false] (cond-> initial-number a inc b (#(+ 5 %)))) => 0
```